# In my face recognition attendance marking system exit button cannot working

Tags: python

```
PS C:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects> cd "c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects"
PS C:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects> python -u "c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py"
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:37: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  img1=img1.resize((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:207: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  img=img.resize((1366,130),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:216: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  bg1=bg1.resize((1366,768),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:232: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  std_img_btn=std_img_btn.resize((180,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:243: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  det_img_btn=det_img_btn.resize((180,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:254: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  att_img_btn=att_img_btn.resize((180,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:265: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
  hlp_img_btn=hlp_img_btn.resize((180,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:279: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.
c:\Users\ARISE\Documents\Python_Test_Projects\login.py:312: DeprecationWarning: ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed in Pillow 10 (2023-07-01). Use Resampling.LANCZOS instead.  exi_img_btn=exi_img_btn.resize((180,180),Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

**The above mentioned error are shoving in my vs code terminal**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1n3U.jpg)
In the above attached image I have shown you which type of problem I am facing. The cross button which i marked above is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The `Image.ANTIALIAS` is no longer used, you've to use `Image.Resampling.LANCZOS` for the later versions of pillow.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html

For the close button to work, you can use `Image.close()`